# Rectangle program not accurate

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program, that will ask users for the length and width of a rectangle, where the length and width will be portrayed with a * symbol.The program actually works well, it's just adding an extra symbol, and I do not know why.

E.g, I enter 5 for the length , and 4 for the width, my output will end up looking like:

```
          xxxxxx
          x    x
          x    x
          x    x
          xxxxxx
```

These dimensions above me are actually 6x5, even though I put 5x4 in the program.

I would want the program to look like this, 
Expected output:

```
        xxxxx
        x   x
        x   x
        xxxxx
```

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class aps{
public static void main(String [] args){ 

    //Declaring variables
    int length, width;

    //Prompting user for length
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the length of your rectangle: ");
    length = scanner.nextInt();// integer i for rows(width)

    //Prompting user for width
    System.out.print("Enter the width of your rectangle: ");
    width = scanner.nextInt();//integer j for columns(length)

    //Processing
    for(int i = 0; i<=width; i++){  //first loop
        for(int j = 0; j<=length; j++){ //second loop
            if(i==0||j==0||j==length||i==width){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

        }// end of second loop

        System.out.println();

    } //end of first loop


    }
}
```

Comment: Where is it adding an extra symbol? You've shown us the expected output, but show us the actual output too.

Comment: @kaya3 The output is 6x5 not 5x4.

Comment: You wrote `i<=width` and `j<=length`. That means you go from 0 to 5 *inclusive* and from 0 to 4 *inclusive*. How many numbers are that? 6 and 5, not 5 and 4. (Hint: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: If the problem is that the rectangle that gets printed is too wide and too tall, please clarify the question - "adding an extra symbol" doesn't really explain this. I understood the first block to be an example of the expected output.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, sorry this is my second post on this website, still getting used to the format of the posts.Thank you.

Comment: @Max Vollmer okay, so do I start the loop at int i = 1;?

Comment: That's not a problem, but please edit the question to clarify what your program *should* do, what it *does* do, and what the difference is.

Comment: @kaya3 I’ve just edited my question, hopefully this makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: @JeevenNullatamby Remember to mark an answer as accepted (click the green checkmark under the downvote) if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a for loop to run something `n` times, you need the for loop to be in the form `for(int i=0; i < n; i++)` or `for(int i=1; i <= n; i++)` instead of `for(int i=0; i <= n; i++)`, which runs `n+1` times (i.e once for 0, then `n` times from `1..n`).

An easy fix for you would be to just get change the `<=` to `<` in your for loop conditions, as well as changing the `if` condition to reflect the change:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class aps{
public static void main(String [] args){ 

    //Declaring variables
    int length, width;

    //Prompting user for length
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the length of your rectangle: ");
    length = scanner.nextInt();// integer i for rows(width)

    //Prompting user for width
    System.out.print("Enter the width of your rectangle: ");
    width = scanner.nextInt();//integer j for columns(length)

    //Processing
    for(int i = 0; i<width; i++){  //first loop
        for(int j = 0; j<length; j++){ //second loop
            if(i==0||j==0||j==length-1||i==width-1){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

        }// end of second loop

        System.out.println();

    } //end of first loop


    }
}
```

Comment: When I change the conditions from <= to < it removes half of the rectangle.

Comment: @JeevenNullatamby you would need to change the if condition as well, I updated my answer to reflect that.